# Sorting teams in group by 3 variables (wins, loses and seed)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm working on a tournament project and was looking for good sorting method to sort teams in group by its wins, loses and seed.

Group object:

```json
[
  {
    "groupId": 1,
    "signature": "A",
    "teams": [
        "team": {
          "id": 45,
          "name": "Team A",
          "seed": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "TOP"
          },
          "wins": 0,
          "loses": 0
   },
        "team": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Team B",
          "seed": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "HIGH"
          },
          "wins": 0,
          "loses": 0
   } etc.
```

Seed order looks like this: TOP -> HIGH -> MID -> LOW

I have a group A:

1. Team A TOP | 0:0
2. Team B HIGH | 0:0
3. Team C MID | 0:0
4. Team D LOW | 0:0

In this case it's easy to sort this group (using seed, obviously), but how do I sort them by wins and loses?

Let's say some matches were played already:

Case 1:

1. Team B HIGH | 2:0
2. Team A TOP | 1:1
3. Team D LOW | 1:1
4. Team C MID | 0:2

Case 2:

1. Team A TOP | 2:1
2. Team B HIGH | 2:1
3. Team D LOW | 1:2
4. Team C MID | 0:3

How to sort teams when (case 1) teamAWins = teamDWins and teamALoses = teamDLoses and then sort those two by seed? As well as in case 2, where team A has the same wins and loses amount as teamB?
Is it possible? If not, how to do it using only wins and loses?

Thanks in advice. I really need that help.

Comment: do you have some examples with data and result?

Comment: Data: JSON in thread
Result: those two cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for getting the right numerical value for `seed` and sort by

- `wins` ascending,
- `loses` descending and
- `seeds` with the numerical value ascending.

```js
const seeds = { TOP: 1, HIGH: 2, MID: 3, LOW: 4 };

array.sort((a, b) =>
    a.wins - b.wins ||
    b.loses - a.loses ||
    seeds[a.seed.name] - seeds[a.seed.name]
);
```